# During the twitter feud, why is it shown as Neil did not know who Rajesh was?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

In the previous seasons it is shown Rajesh talking casually with Neil.

Check out the video:

It's clearly shown here, Tyson knows Rajesh then why in the later season in the meteor shower episode during the Twitter feud it's shown that Tyson does not know who is this Rajesh Astrophysicist guy talking ill about him?

Check out the video: